# Can the Circle Of Wildfire druid's Enhanced Bond, give the ability to have multiple origin for the multi ray spell type?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, spellcasting, druid

> In addition, when you cast a spell with a range other than self, the spell can originate from you or your wildfire spirit.

If I cast a multiple ray spell such as Scorching Ray or Eldritch Blast, can I split the origin of the rays? Or do I have to choose one origin for all my rays when I cast the spell?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### “Or”, not “and”: you may choose one or the other, not both.

When choosing where the spell originates from, you are given the option to choose “you” *or* “your wildfire spirit”. You make the choice, and then “the spell”, that is, the entire spell effect, originates from the chosen creature (you or your spirit). Splitting the rays up between you and your spirit would be the spell originating from “you *and* your wildfire spirit” (with language making it optional), which is not what the feature description says.

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. Saying "and" would lead people to think that the spell comes from both locations at once; *A* spell from you *and* someone else. It sounds like a ziplock spell. Or even worse, the same spell is duplicated. For actual clarity, the feature would need to call out what happens when a single spell has multiple aspects.

Comment: I would argue that, if one or more rays came from one origin, and one or more rays also come from a different origin, then the spell *is* coming from multiple locations at once, since all of the rays are emanating from a single instance of the spell. Therefore the title to this answer is correct; "or" indicates the single spell may originate from either origin but not both, whereas "and" would imply that the spell originates from multiple places, and therefore rays could emaninate from multiple origins.